# Got NullPointerException during editing chart plot at Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to access the "Chart Plot" tab of my bar chart in order to change the orientation to horizontal but I'm getting this error with no further details

[image]

This error also appears when I click this tab on the other pie chart of the file.

This is the jrxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.13.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.13.0-46ada4d1be8f3c5985fd0b6146f3ed44caed6f05  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="consumption_template" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="c2376118-5b9b-47c0-b7d6-a20b65a05ffb">
    <subDataset name="totalKgClothesPieDataSet" uuid="72727fea-d56b-46dd-8104-9ddbf35dad68">
        <parameter name="params" class="com.dosiper.laundryserver.laundry.statistics.consumption.dto.export.equipment.pdf.ExportConsumptionPDFParameters"/>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="kgRealPercentage" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="totalKgClothesBarDataSet" uuid="cc72577b-9c33-4f93-bc5a-0460f7084532">
        <parameter name="params" class="com.dosiper.laundryserver.laundry.statistics.consumption.dto.export.equipment.pdf.ExportConsumptionPDFParameters"/>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="kgReal" class="java.lang.Double"/>
    </subDataset>
    <parameter name="params" class="com.dosiper.laundryserver.laundry.statistics.consumption.dto.export.equipment.pdf.ExportConsumptionPDFParameters"/>
    <field name="totalKgClothesPieDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <field name="totalKgClothesBarDataSource" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <group name="TotalKgClothes">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="552">
                <pieChart>
                    <chart isShowLegend="false" evaluationTime="Report">
                        <reportElement key="" positionType="Float" isPrintRepeatedValues="false" x="8" y="160" width="540" height="392" uuid="f656a8cf-a3d7-48ee-8128-a7fac530f9ca"/>
                        <chartTitle>
                            <font fontName="Arial" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                            <titleExpression><![CDATA[$P{params}.getTotalKgClothesPieChartTitle()]]></titleExpression>
                        </chartTitle>
                        <chartSubtitle/>
                        <chartLegend/>
                    </chart>
                    <pieDataset maxCount="30">
                        <dataset resetType="Report">
                            <datasetRun subDataset="totalKgClothesPieDataSet" uuid="e50e959c-3556-430b-97b2-c9bc4ccc10f2">
                                <datasetParameter name="params">
                                    <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{params}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                                </datasetParameter>
                                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{totalKgClothesPieDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                            </datasetRun>
                        </dataset>
                        <keyExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></keyExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{kgRealPercentage}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}.toLowerCase()]]></labelExpression>
                    </pieDataset>
                    <piePlot>
                        <plot/>
                        <itemLabel/>
                    </piePlot>
                </pieChart>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
    <group name="TotalKgClothesBarChart">
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="367">
                <barChart>
                    <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                        <reportElement x="8" y="10" width="542" height="350" uuid="d4072751-ba5d-4c03-8a2d-f2ab02960e59"/>
                        <chartTitle>
                            <font fontName="Arial" size="14" isBold="true"/>
                            <titleExpression><![CDATA[$P{params}.getTotalKgClothesBarChartTitle()]]></titleExpression>
                        </chartTitle>
                        <chartSubtitle/>
                        <chartLegend/>
                    </chart>
                    <categoryDataset>
                        <dataset resetType="Report">
                            <datasetRun subDataset="totalKgClothesBarDataSet" uuid="a763eb3e-b77a-4976-9264-475e19713a73">
                                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$F{totalKgClothesBarDataSource}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                            </datasetRun>
                        </dataset>
                        <categorySeries>
                            <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></seriesExpression>
                            <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></categoryExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{kgReal}]]></valueExpression>
                            <labelExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></labelExpression>
                        </categorySeries>
                    </categoryDataset>
                    <barPlot>
                        <plot/>
                        <itemLabel/>
                        <categoryAxisFormat>
                            <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                        </categoryAxisFormat>
                        <valueAxisFormat>
                            <axisFormat labelColor="#000000" tickLabelColor="#000000" axisLineColor="#000000"/>
                        </valueAxisFormat>
                    </barPlot>
                </barChart>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
</jasperReport>
```

If possible, do you know how to edit the jrxml file to add the "horizontal" orientation manually?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be something related to version 6.13.0, it works with version "6.12.2" so I just opened an issue in their bug tracker.

Thanks.